# Background Image Center and Resize WITHOUT Keeping Aspect Ratio

Tags: html, css, web, dreamweaver

```
body {
background: url(images/Background.png) no-repeat center center scroll;
-webkit-background-size: cover
-moz-backgroun  d-size: cover
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover
}
```

So basically I need to change the above code to resize WITHOUT keeping the aspect ratio.

Thanks in advance for him who helps me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
background-size:100% 100%;
```

Comment: Thanks, but instead of Dreamweaver accepting the "percent" sign (100% 100%), it took it as meaning 100 x 100 pixels. :)

Comment: Then don't use Dreamweaver :)

Comment: Just like with any tool -- it'll make your life easier to an extent, but when you need something specific -- you'll have to do it yourself. Though it's hard to believe that Dreamweaver doesn't understand percentages